# ¿Cómo puedo pasar un array con objetos por ajax a django?

Tags: python, ajax, python-3.x, django

Cuando intento pasar objetos dentro de un array por ajax a django, no funciona

En PYTHON

```
request.POST.getlist('datos[]')
```

En JS

```
data : {'datos':datos,csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}' },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logré solucionarlo de esta manera:

### en PYTHON

```
 import json <br>
 datos = request.POST.getlist('datos[]')<br>
 datos_list = json.loads(datos[0])
```

### en JS

```
"dataType": "json",<br>
 data : {'datos[]':JSON.stringify(datos),csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Probá usando `datos[]` en vez de `datos`:

```
data : {'datos[]': datos, csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}' },
```

Comment: De la forma en que lo estás haciendo no funciona? Que error te tira en pantalla?

Comment: De la forma en que tú me indicaste funciona bien, pasa el array con objetos. Ahora lo que no puedo es tomar los valores de los objetos contenidos en el array. No me tira ningún error, solo no encuentro la vuelta para tomar los valores.

Comment: Podés hacer `lista_de_datos = request.POST.getlist('datos[]')` y despues recorrer la lista con un `for`. Si tenés problemas con eso podrías abrir otra pregunta en Stack para encontrar soluciones más específicas.

Comment: Por favor, recuerda de marcar como correcta la respuesta si te ayudó con el problema para dar por cerrada la pregunta y contribuir con la comunidad. Saludos!